# Limit on foreach loop

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this query for show wordpress themes in select tag:

```
$themeNames = list of wordpress themes
$ipadTheme = detect ipad devices
$defaultTheme = wordpress active theme

              foreach ($themeNames as $themeName) {
                  if (($ipadTheme == $themeName) || (($ipadTheme == '') && ($themeName == $defaultTheme))) {
                      echo '<option value="' . $themeName . '" selected="selected">' . htmlspecialchars($themeName) . '</option>';
                  } else {
                      echo'<option value="' . $themeName . '">' . htmlspecialchars($themeName) . '</option>';
                  }
              }
```

this code showing list on wordpress themes.

but i want to show just 2 option!

1. active theme
2. my personal theme

how I have to change it?

and its possible to change it to radio button as turn off/on ?

I mean I write 2 radio button, turn off = default theme - turn of = my personal theme

thanks.

Comment: Please include more code? What is $themeNames and $ipadTheme? Do you have an image of what you want to be?

Comment: @Muhammad Esmaili that is not much of an update. What is the difference between active theme and personal theme?

Comment: I have 2 themes.
1 : a active theme for Desktop version
2 : a deactive theme for Mobile version!

when I turn on it or select mobile theme from select list,  mobile visitors can see mobile theme!

Comment: And this option will be available to visitors or only admin?

Comment: its for admin.
admin can set this option turn off or on